# Basis in $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, measure-theory

Consider the space $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$. Show that the functions $f_0(x)=1,f_1(x)=x,f_2(x)=x^2,\ldots $ form a basis.

The functions are linearly independent (no linear combination adds up to zero). But for them to form a basis, doesn't their linear combination have to hit all functions in $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$? Surely not all functions in $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ can be written as a polynomial. Or does "basis" carry a different meaning in this context?

Comment: The problem here is you're referring to an infinite sum of polynomials as a polynomial.

Comment: @GitGud No, I'm considering a polynomial as only a **finite** linear combination of the $f_i(x)$'s

Comment: Not all functions in the set are polynomials, but all of them might be written as a power series.

Comment: @GitGud I see. So, does the definition of a basis allow for an **infinite** linear combination of the basis elements? This I really don't know.

Comment: There are different types of "basis". There are bases in the linear algebra sense (finite linear combinations), those are also called Hamel bases. For Hilbert spaces, there are orthonormal systems $u_\alpha$ such that every vector can be written as a series $x = \sum\limits_\alpha c_\alpha\cdot u_\alpha$, with only countably many coefficients nonzero. These are known as orthonormal bases or Hilbert bases. Then there are also Schauder bases $e_n$, where you have for each vector a unique representation $x = \sum_n c_n e_n$ such that the sequence of partial sums converges.

Comment: Probably, this question asks you to show that the monomials form a Schauder basis.

Comment: Which I think they don't, by the way.

Comment: Continuous functions are dense in $L^2([0,1])$, and continuous functions are continuously approximated by polynomials (Stone-Weierstrass theorem). So the set of all polynomials is dense in $L^2([0,1])$. This is the essence, I believe, of what the question is asking.