# Writing $f\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ as a power series.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, power-series

Consider the space $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$. I want to show that every function $f\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ can be written as a power series.

I remember a result that polynomials are dense in $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$. I thought about extending it (since power series are polynomials with infinite number of terms), but it is not clear how to do that. Density means that polynomials can get arbitrarily close to a function $f$, but here we want an exact representation.

(Note: See also [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549081/basis-in-l2-pi-pi))

Comment: You will have some difficulty doing that, as it is not true.

Comment: Good question. The answer is that you can't.

Comment: Interesting! Is it easy to construct a counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $f\in L^2\cap L^\infty[-\pi,\pi]$ can be written as a power series, at least almost everywhere on a neighborhood $V$ of $0$. Then we should have $\lVert f(\cdot+t)-f(\cdot)\rVert_{L^\infty(V)}\to 0$. But it's not necessarily the case (consider $\chi_{[0,\delta)}$). In particular $f$ does not necessarily coincide with a continuous function.

Answer (score 3):

The Dirichlet function 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x \in \mathbb Q \\0 & x \notin \mathbb Q \end{cases} $$
is in $L^2 ([-\pi,\pi])$, and nowhere analytic (i.e. it lacks a power series representation for *all* points).

Comment: Yes, but $f=0$ almost everywhere meaning $f$ and $0$ define the same element of $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ and $0$ has a power series